# datetime conversion too long for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I look for converting index read by read_csv in datetime but it takes a very long time (more than 1 minutes).

Is someone know an more efficient way (other command, using cython, ...)?

```
>>> df
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 3367200 entries, 2014/02/28 to 2017/12/31
Columns: 3 entries, SCENARIO to 0
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: Are you parsing the dates with read_csv ?

Comment: I do df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', index_col=[0,1]) and date is in col1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`parse_dates` argument for `read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), that way it's read in directly as a datetime64 (int64) rather than a string (and then having to parse that):

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # in python 2
a = '''date,A,B
1/1/2014,1,2
1/1/2014,2,3'''

In [11]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(a), index_col=[0, 1], parse_dates=[0])
Out[11]: 
              B
date       A   
2014-01-01 1  2
           2  3
```

Comment: @user3442271 out of interest, how did this affect the timings for you?

Comment: This way reduce the timings by half on my side. By problem is I have values for hours initialy in 24 columns and date in first one. So I have to be more efficient as I can because after, I have to stach columns and do an apply to do a relativedelta on the datetime (which is take actually 2 min more)...

Comment: @user3442271 sounds interseting, perhaps could make a new question about that reshaping aspect! :)

Comment: I have done one for this typical problem {too long dataframe apply row functions}. I am very suprising if I am the first person to deal with this problem.

Comment: @user3442271 ah! checking out the other question